# Android - avoiding intent sniffing

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to understand the statement made by via forensics on this [page](https://viaforensics.com/resources/reports/best-practices-ios-android-secure-mobile-development/android-intent-sniffing/):

> When an activity is started by another application using a Broadcast Intent 
>   the data passed in the Intent can be read by a malicious app. The malicious 
>   app can also read a list of recent Intents for an application. For example, 
>   when the Android Web browser is invoked by an app which passes it a URL, that 
>   URL can be sniffed.
>
> It is recommended that sensitive data should not be passed between apps 
>   using Broadcast Intents.

My questions are :

1) How can an activity be started using broadcast intent ?

2) How does malicious application read list of recent intents for an application ?

Comment: I agree with Emmanuel on point 1. I think they worded it badly and they mean an explicit `Intent` with an action such as `ACTION_VIEW` for a particular document type etc etc. I also think the other part is worded badly - I don't believe a malicious app can "read a list of recent Intents" but it could intercept/sniff Intents and *maintain* its own list of what has recently headed your way. In other words, if it's active at the time your app is receiving Intents then it could build a picture of what is going on and potentially compromise security/confidentiality.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Squonk.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) How can an activity be started using broadcast intent ?

You send an explicit `Intent` that matches the `IntentFilter` of the target `Activity`

> 2) How does malicious application read list of recent intents for an application ?

I do not know if you can get a list, but a malicious app can simply use the same `IntentFilters` as the non-malicious app and sniff your `Intents`.